# Open Scripting Architecture Reference

Tags: applescript

Lots of documents, like [this one](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptX/Concepts/osa.html), refer to the "Open Scripting Architecture Reference," which sounds useful to me. But I can't find it anywhere. Googling the title gets lots of non-authoritative links where people have posted old PDFs of what presumably is an earlier version of the same thing.

Where is it?

Comment: The API for that was implemented in OpenScripting.framework, a subframework of Carbon.framework. Since Carbon was deprecated on Mountain Lion 10.8. Are you looking for a deep link to the old documentation or just confirmation that the current docs are current and to ignore the old links that are removed since they are deprecated?

Comment: So, I'm trying to figure how to use the new JavaScript implementation. See https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/InterapplicationCommunication/RN-JavaScriptForAutomation/Articles/OSX10-10.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014508-CH109-SW6 ... It doesn't supply a reference, really (just lists some global objects), and points to OSA documentation for more information, which is how I arrived at thinking I wanted this document. Am I on the wrong road?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at https://applescriptlibrary.wordpress.com or use the search engine of your choice. The exact document you ask is here:

- https://applescriptlibrary.files.wordpress.com/2013/11/open-scripting-architecture.pdf

It's listed as legacy and from 2007. See my comment above about carbon API such as this being deprecated when 10.8 Mountain Lion was released. It might be better to just use the current guide you linked above unless you have specific needs to do research or support older OS and tools.